# Extract read position from bam file

Tags: r, perl, bioinformatics, bioconductor, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a vcf file that contains several SNPs and now I want to see, whether these SNPs are evenly distributed over the reads of the bam file from which I got the SNPs. Specifically, I want to plot the number of SNPs over read position.
I am wondering whether there is some tool around for doing this or whether I have to write a script on my own. If so, is there a package in R with which I can do that (I am used to R but don't have much experience with perl)?

Comment: you should ask biostar : http://biostar.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what 'SNPs over read position' means, but you could read the VCF with the R / [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) package and function VariantAnnotation::readVcf, and use the genomic coordinates to query the bam file with Rsamtools::countBam, using `ScanBamParam`. Without testing, along the lines of

```
## first-time installation
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite(c("VariantAnnotation", "Rsamtools"))
```

to install the relevant packages, and then

```
library(VariantAnnotation) # also loads Rsamtools
snps = readVcf("/some/file.vcf")
param = ScanBamParam(which=rowData(vcf))
reads = countBam("/some/file.bam", param=param)
```

The best way to implement this might depend alot on how many SNPs you're interested in. I'd suggest that you use the pre-release R-2.15 alpha, as you will then get a more recent set of Bioconductor packages. These packages have extensive vignettes (`vignette(package="VariantAnnotation")` and knowledgeable people on the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/), as well as the usual help pages `?readVcf`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try that. With 'number of SNPs over read position' I mean that I want to have on the x-axis all bases of a read (in the case of an Illumina read 100 bp) and on the y-axis the cumulative number of SNPs that were found on that base position. An example is shown in this paper, figure 2: biomedcentral.com/1471-2164/12/150 . Is it possible to do such things with the packages you specified?